# Android automated testing in Cloud

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso, testdroid

We have whole ui test suite written in Espresso for our app, we are trying to figure out best service to run this test on whole matrix of device and api's

I came across few services:

1. TestDroid - Looks like runs at about $49/mo and supports espresso tests, I have been playing around with their free account, it works nice, but I am wondering how well they support CI
2. Test Object - I guess you cannot use the trial version for automated test and it starts at about $199/mo. There manual test featured looks nice, I am just wondering why is this so expensive?
3. AWS Device Farm/App Thwak - Look like its really new and I didn't see any support for espresso tests.

Any input would be great in making decision on which service to go with?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using AWS Device Farm.

The Android test system has been updated to be based on JUnit 4 during summer 2015 and the new implementation is working well on AWS.

Be careful, to make it work on AWS Device Farm, *all your test methods have to start with "testXYZ()" or the farm will not detect them.* and your test classes have to end with "Test".

There is a AWS Farm Device available with Jenkins and Gradle (for Android Studio integration). Also Spoon screenshot are embedded within AWS Device Farm test results.